# Driving 4.2V TFT by 5V

Tags: raspberry-pi, 5v, conversion, mobile, tft

I have a nooby question:
Is it within the range of tolerance to drive a TFT (car electronics 4.3 inch low cost type) which runs on 4.2V internally (12V DCDC-converted to 4.2V by an 'XL1509 adjustable output') by 5V from my Raspberry Pi directly without frying it?

The converter handles 5V as direct input quite well, but if possible I would like to get rid of the inefficiency of the converter and the additional heat. As a last option I would think about replacing the converter by a diode, which probably results in less energy loss...

Thanks for all advice!

Comment: Range of tolerance of the TFT: check the datasheet. Efficiency and heat: that depends on the current that the TFT draws, but since it is a switching converter don't worry about it too much. It is protected against overload. Only if the XL1509 gets very hot your efficiency is bad. Replacing the converter by a diode will probably give a similar loss of energy. The voltage drop of 5 V to 4.2 V is quite small, you cannot lose much power there. Unless the TFT module consumes a lot of amps (more than 4A or so) which I doubt.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and advice on the diode/conversion differences.
I am not aware how hot the whole thing should get, but it is noticeably hotter where the pcb is.

In addition I think I won't be able to find a datasheet for the TFT, since it is coming straight out of a most likely china-made car-camera TFT.

Comment: Wasn't able to edit anymore:

The video chip is an AMT630, which according to the datasheet should run on 3.3V. I haven't seen any further downstepping, but can the heat issue come from the fact that the whole pcb should run on 3.3V but the first DCDC conversion to 4.2V has gone wrong and is too high?

Comment: According to the datasheet the AMT630 uses 2 3.3 V supplies of 50 mA each so 100 mA total 3.3 * 0.1 = 0.33 W. That's not that much, a PCB would get a little bit warm from that but certainly not hot. Probably there's a linear regulator on the PCB to take the 4.2 down to 3.3 V. It would also get slightly warm. If the TFT PCB is warm but not so warm that you cannot touch it for a long time: don't worry about it. If it gets too hot to touch: there's a problem.

Comment: The best would be to just measure that the 4.2 V to the TFT board is actually 4.2 V, if it is then all should be OK.

Comment: Dear FakeMoustache,
thanks for the information, which I wasn't able to read from the data sheet and the valuable comparison for the heat. I didn't touch the components on the pcb themselves, but I will certainly do when I have time for the next test. I think I should be able to touch them, they won't be hotter than 60ºC I think, judging from the front side of the TFT.
I'm sorry I can't upvote your comments 'useful', because you all certainly deserved it. I feel more confident about what I'm doing already. Thanks again!

Comment: My pleasure :-)

Comment: So I got around to fetch a temperature probe, however it is not made to measure the temperature of flat surfaces, - basically it ends in a cone of 3mm base width. So depending on the contact area I get different readings.
With this setup I measure 55°C for the DCDC converter and about 50°C for the TFT driver chip, it's memory and some other basic components.
This is underlined by the fact that it is not possible for me to put my finger to the converter for longer than some seconds.
The measurement has been made at 5V, I expect the same for 12V, though, since the outside temp felt the same.

Comment: 55 degrees C is warm but still OK, electronics can easily handle that. I would only worry when above 70 C.

Comment: Yeqh, I don't worry about the temperature for the chips sake, this is in easily capable condition. I just wonder whether I can save all that lost endery since I get the feeling that I might run the RPi for an additional hour from the battery from this lost energy alone ;-)
I will check out the enrgy intake of the screen this afternoon, since I cut the wire to fit it to the GPIO pins yesterday night, enabling multimeter use on the whole screen unit at least.

Comment: Indeed it sounds like the display module is not very power efficient. Since it is low cost and intended for use in a car, I expect power efficiency was not a concern when it was designed. Unfortunately I doubt if there's anything you can do about that.

Comment: Thanks, FakeMoustache. I get that feeling as well.
The current is 0.42A, resulting in 2.1W (0.14A when no video signal is supplied - this means no backlight as well). I have the feeling that this is what should be suspected for such a screen.
Thanks for all your help again!
I will look around for comparison values and see whether I stick with this screen or not ;)

Answer (score 2):

Be careful using a diode for its voltage drop. Voltage drop is a function of current for a real diode. Lower current -> lower voltage drop. Voltage drop is also affected by temperature. I'd definitely use the XL1509.

If your converter is getting hot, measure the input current and output current. Then look at how much power you're losing (Vin * Iin - Vout * Iout). The check the XL1509 datasheet to see if that looks right.

Comment: Dear Chad,
thanks for your ideas and tips, I didn't even think about the warnings regarding the diode use, and if I had, I'd probably thought of them as negligible.

However, I also thought about measuring the power differences, but I don't really know how to do that on a pcb, since I cannot disconnect the wires to put my multimeter in-line. A quick search on the internet didn't yield applicable results, is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Sorry, missed that the XL1509 was already on a PCB. Do you have a temperature probe? Just curious how hot it gets when driven by 5V. I would think it would not get very hot.

Comment: Dear Chad, see the discussion above if you're interested, I measured the temperatures today. More to follow this afternoon.